# Fall in the middle of a tag at the end of a tag

Tags: css

I want the middle of the arrow to be exactly the percent of the end and the beginning of the line.
Do not use pixels as each may change its width.

https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GA6FZF1EE3BF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `transform:translate(px)`, I used -5px to position it correctly. This will work even the width of the line is adjusted.

Try to change the width of .my-line on the snippet below and it the arrows will still retain their translated positions.

```
.my-line {
  position: relative;
  background-color: gray;
  height: 5px;
  margin-top: 70px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

Run snippet below;

```css
.my-line {
  position: relative;
  background-color: gray;
  height: 5px;
  margin-top: 70px;
  width: 100px;
}

.my-line #left {
  position: absolute;
  top: -15px;
  left: 100%;
  transform: translate(-5px);
}

.my-line #right {
  position: absolute;
  top: -15px;
  left: 0;
  transform: translate(-5px);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-UHRtZLI+pbxtHCWp1t77Bi1L4ZtiqrqD80Kn4Z8NTSRyMA2Fd33n5dQ8lWUE00s/" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="my-line">
      <span id="left" class="fa fa-caret-down"></span>
    </div>

    <div class="my-line">
      <span id="right" class="fa fa-caret-down"></span>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Where did the 4px number come from?
and
What is the difference with margin-left: -5px;?

Comment: @Ali the difference between `margin-left:-5px` and `transform:translate(-5px)` is that in transform:translate still retains the original position of the element, then it is just visually moved. In margin, when the element is moved, the other DOM elements are affected. In transform, the other elements are not affected.